# Express.js sending response in promise .catch() error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function x(req, res, next){

    await doSomething().catch(error =>{

        return res.send('error here'})

        }
    await doSomethingElse().catch(error =>{console.log(error)})

    return res.send('success');

}
```

When doSomething() returns an error, I get  "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", which I understand, but why doesn't the script terminate when I call the first res.send?

My guess is that it's similar to a callback in that the returned value is ignored, so it sends the response, but ignores the fact that the script should end there.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't mix up `await` and `then/catch`. Use one of them.

Comment: Your `catch` can be executed after `return res.send('success');`

Answer (score 1):

It gets very complicated to control flow when you are mixing `.catch()` and `await`.  I would strongly suggest using only one model at a time.  With await, you can do this:

```
async function x(req, res, next) {
    try {
        await doSomething();
        await doSomethingElse();
        res.send('success');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.send('error here'})
    }
}
```

> why doesn't the script terminate when I call the first res.send?

Because the `return` in that statement just returns back from the `.catch()` handler not from your main function and since you've done a `.catch()` and not thrown inside that catch handler or returned a rejected promise from the handler, then the parent promise because resolved and execution after the `await` continues just fine which then causes you to run into the second `res.send()` which causes the warning about headers already sent.

Comment: @JonathanZier - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `.then()` `.catch()` just try:

```
function x(req, res, next) {
  doSomething()
    .catch((error) => {
      return res.send("error here");
    })
    .then(() => {
      doSomethingElse()
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(() => {
          return res.send("success");
        });
    });
}
```